# How can I force a component to unmount when I navigate to a new page in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I have a homepage with a link to a form, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  NavLink,
  Redirect,
  Switch,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom"; 
import addHand from './Forms/addHand'

export class Home extends Component { 

  render() { 
      return ( 
        <div> 
          <Router> 
          <div>
          <NavLink to= '/hands/new'> Add a new hand </NavLink> 
          <Route path= '/hands/new' component={addHand}/> 
          <h4> Search For Hands By Category </h4> 
          <h4> Search For Sessions By Category </h4> 
          <h4> Search For Tables By Category </h4> 
          </div> 
          </Router>
        </div> 
      ); 
  }
} 

export default Home;
```

I also have a navbar with a link to go home from any page, like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';  
import unmountComponentAtNode from 'react-dom';

class NavBar extends Component { 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navbar"> 
        <NavLink className="link"
        to="/"
        exact 
      >Home</NavLink> 
      </div>
    ); 
  }
};

export default NavBar;
```

If I go to the form, then change my mind and decide I want to go back to the homepage, the url changes when I press the navlink, but the form is still rendered on the homepage. I can keep going back and forth between routes, but the only way to get the form to unmount from the DOM is to refresh the page. What causes this behavior, and what can I do to fix it? I have experienced similar issues before in React but have never found the solution. Thanks!

Edit** I tried adding this to the navlink:

```
render() {

const refCallback = node => {
  unmountComponentAtNode(node)
}

return (
  <div className="navbar"> 
    <NavLink className="link"
    to="/"
    exact 
    innerRef={refCallback}
  >Home</NavLink> 
  </div>
); 
}
};
```

as per the react router docs, but it gives me this error:

unmountComponentAtNode(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Here is the code in app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css'; 
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import Home from './Components/Home'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import addHand from './Components/Forms/addHand';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title-top">Hi Adam, welcome to your Personal 
Poker Universe!</h1> 
          <h1 className="App-title-middle">Not Adam? GTFO!</h1> 
          <h1 className="App-title-bottom">Just Kidding, you can stay</h1>
        </header> 
        <Router history= {history}> 
          <div>
        <Navbar/> 
        <Route exact path='/' component= {Home} />   
        </div>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: which form you're talking about?

Comment: is it add Hand? where have you defined Home route?

Comment: Yes addhand is the form. The home route is defined in app.js

Comment: Please share your app.js

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Okay I added it

Comment: did you try state ?

Answer (score 0):

Define one `Router` in your App.js:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />} />
    <Route  path="/hands/new" component={addHand} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

then try navigating between routes it should work. Please Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Hmmm. If I do that then Home.js doesn't display at all, just the navbar. If I put a div inside the switch, then Home.js displays, but when I click the link to go to addHand, the url changes but the form is not displayed